# How to pass an array to a method in C and edit the contents?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, methods

Basically I have this working code that manipulates an array of strings:

```
for (i = 0; i < numentries; i++)
    if (strcmp(compare_str, strings[i]) < 0)
        break;
    for (j = numentries; j > i; j--)
        strcpy(strings[j], strings[j - 1]);
    strcpy(strings[i], compare_str);
    strcat(strings[i], " ");
    strcat(strings[i], whole_str);

numentries++;
```

I want to make it so I can call to a method to do the manipulation like:

```
//call to method
compare(strings, numentries, compare_str, whole_str);
    numentries++;


//method
void compare(char array[], int entries, char compare[], char whole[]) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < entries; i++)
        if (strcmp(compare, array[i]) < 0)
            break;
    for (j = entries; j > i; j--)
        strcpy(array[j], array[j - 1]);

    strcpy(array[i], compare);
    strcat(array[i], " ");
    strcat(array[i], whole);
}
```

The above code doesn't work, I know you have to use pointers some how much im not exactly sure how. How do I pass my array of characters (strings) so I can manipulate the values inside the array?

I know this is only a code snippet, but I thought it would be enough to solve my problem. if you need more of my program to help me let me know.

It crashes at the line

```
strcat(array[i], " ");
```

with the message

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. 0x75bf8df6 in strcat () from C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll n Single stepping until exit from function strcat, which has no line number information. 0x77776299 in ntdll!LdrGetDllHandleByName () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll

Comment: i am sure you are missing some `{` and `}`

Comment: its only a snippet of my code, hopefully enough to get my question across? I didn't want to upload my whole program, I just need help on this one part.

Comment: @esskar: it's awkward without the `{}`, but they aren't required anywhere he doesn't have them.

Comment: There are some other issues, too, such as where the last part may be writing off the end of the array, assuming that the loop exited because i == entries. It is hard to tell the exact semantics of entries here.

Comment: how is `strings` declared in the calling code?

Comment: @AShelly
char strings[30][160 + 1]; I still need help so if you think you can help please feel free to try anything

Comment: As an aside, it seems that this function should be called `insertIntoSortedWordList` or some such.  The function's primary purpose is not to compare. And having a function and an argument with the same name is confusing.

Comment: @AShelly you are right, ill change that in my code

Answer (score 1):

```
void compare(char *array[], int entries, char compare[], char whole[]) {
                  ^
```

Proof: http://ideone.com/6xSaq

Comment: Technically, shouldn't it be `char ((*array)[])[]` if he wants to be verbose about it?

Comment: Steve doesn't like arrays of arrays of chars! LOL

Comment: I'm not sure why you think it's too many indirections - doesn't he want a pointer to an array - which, itself, contains arrays of chars?

Comment: @Steve: I think you meant `char (*(array[])[])`?  Maybe?  It's not an pointer to an _array of arrays_ of chars, it's an array of pointers to arrays of chars.

Comment: this didn't work for me, is there a way I can pm you all my code? - i will still rep you i just need help and don't want to post my whole homework solution online.

Comment: @Steve: in his code, `array` is an array, not a pointer.  As noted by syntax and the name.

Comment: @MooingDuck, Well, that *would* make more sense to *me* (an array of pointers to strings)... but... is that what he really has/wants already? It seems to me like he has/wants an array of arrays of chars.

Comment: @Kingsley: It works in my code.  Edit the question with the full compiler message (In Visual Studio, it's in the _output_ pane, _not_ the error pane), and show us which line number it's referring to.  StackOverflow does not have pms, but we do have chatrooms

Comment: @MooingDuck: `in his code, array is an array, not a pointer. As noted by syntax and the name. ` Yes, but that's the "only" problem.

Comment: @Steve: be careful, an `array of arrays` is a 2d array, which is _very_ different than an array of pointers.  Namely, one dimension must be fixed.

Comment: @MooingDuck, nevermind, you're right... I actually looked at his code now : ) Srrryy.

Comment: @Kingsley: Probably not.  I probably need all of the error code, and the line it refers to.

Comment: @MooingDuck I dont know how to get the line where the error occurs. When I run the program using the method I get "a5q2.exe has stopped working" but without using another method it runs through fine and does its purpose

Comment: @Kingsley: Do you not have a debugger?  If not, making a program work is nigh-impossible.  gdb maybe?

Comment: @MooingDuck I do, but I don't know how to use it that well (im using eclipse) but I will try to get the line of error some how, I really need help.

Comment: @MooingDuck

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x75bf8df6 in strcat () from C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
    
     n      

Single stepping until exit from function strcat,
which has no line number information.
0x77776299 in ntdll!LdrGetDllHandleByName () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll

I guess the problem starts when it trys to concatenate the strings

Answer (score 0):

I would just use a double pointer (pointer to a pointer).  In fact I would just use pointers instead of arrays. Eventually they all boil down to the same thing anyway.

```
void compare(char **array, int entries, char *compare, char *whole) {
```

I don't think any of the body needs to be modified.

EDIT:

Also the segmentation fault you are seeing in your code is probably occuring because of insufficient storage space. If you're using malloc for allocation use realloc to allocate enough space for the string concatenation.  If you're using stack storage, then allocate enough space for every element of the array, incase you need to perform concatenations.

Comment: thanks for the input, but this doesnt work

i get an error at "strcat(array[i], " ");" i am not exactly sure why i get this error

Comment: response to EDIT: I am not using malloc but I dont know why there would not be enough space I have made sure there would be enough when I designed the program. Plus when I run it without using the method, instead embedding the code into the main program it works fine.

Comment: I don't get any compilation errors, I'm assuming this is a runtime error?  If its is the segmentation fault (SIGSEV) that you reported earlier, then its a problem with how you allocated whatever you passed to the function.  Can you please post that part of your code?

Comment: Runtime error or compile error?  What exactly does it say?   Given the definition of strings, you are likely to get a runtime error if `strlen(compare)+strlen(whole)+1 > 160` -- you don't have enough storage to do the concatenation.

Comment: I think I found Kingsley's error: `for (j = entries; j > i; j--)` should be `for (j = entries-1; j > i; j--)`.  Otherwise the index is out of bounds.  When you try to write to that memory, you get SIGSEV.

Comment: @Mrafcho001, that's true only if entries is equal to the declared size of the array. It might be a problem, but if it worked as inline code, it should work here.  There should be some test in the caller to ensure that entries never goes above 30.

Answer (score 0):

Given the declaration `char strings[30][161];`, I think you need the function to be

`void compare(char array[][161], int entries, char compare[], char whole[])`

because you are not passing an array of pointers to chars, you are passing an 2D array of chars.  C needs to know the inner dimension of 2D arrays to do indexing correctly.    [See this article for details](http://c-faq.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx9a.html)

The alternative to hardcoding sizes would be to add something like this before the function call:

```
char* stringPtrs[N_STRINGS];
for (i=0;i<N_STRINGS;i++) { stringPtrs[i]=strings[i]; }
compare(stringPtrs, entries, ...);
```

Comment: let me try this, if it does not work ill show you guys my whole code - thank you guys so much for helping me though I really appreciate it.

Comment: edit: @AShelly this is the closest to working so far, it goes through all the string but when i try to print my output it only prints the first line and nothing for the other ones. off the top of your head do you know why it is doing this?

Comment: See this, which seems to work:   http://ideone.com/1lTv3.   How is it different from your code?

Comment: it is a little bit different ill upload it to ideone and link it here one second

Comment: it works!! nevermind sorry i made a stupid error in my code i found where i messed up thank you so much shelly